# Using SignalR in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: websocket, socket.io, signalr, asp.net-core-1.0

We have an ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC1 application and we want to incorporate SignalR in it. However, SignalR is not yet a part of ASP.NET Core 1.0.

Is there a way to still incorporate SignalR in our existing app or will we have to look into some other web sockets library such as socket.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although SignalR 3 won't be a part of the 1.0 release of ASP.NET Core, you can still use SignalR in an ASP.NET Core web app project.

In fact, check out this SignalR project on the official "aspnet" account on Github:

- https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server

I download the source code, and here's what it looks like in VS2015 (see screenshot below):

[image: SignalR project]

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with SignalR and the upgrade to core 1.0 rtm.
The answer from above does not work anymore so I did the following:

I use this nugget feed:
`https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcirelease/api/v3/index.json`
and this nuget package:
`"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server": "0.1.0-rtm-21431"`

This should help until the first release of SignalR 3

Comment: False alarm. Was using a newer version. The history doesn't go that far back. Any chance of this package being pulled at some point?